# How is right way to insert many rows in redstone_mapper_pg?

Tags: postgresql, asynchronous, dart

I use redstone_mapper_pg and I need to insert many rows to database table:

```
class Rate {
  @Field() String zone_id;
  @Field() String cost;
}

@app.Route("/rplan", methods: const [app.POST])
addRPlan(@Decode() List<Rate> rate) async {
  try {
    await pgsql.execute('begin');
    rate.forEach((row) async {
      try {
        await pgsql.execute('insert into t_rate (zone_id,cost) '
          'values (@zone_id,@cost)', row);
      } catch(err) {
        await pgsql.execute('rollback');
        return new Future.error(err);
      }
    });
  } catch(err) {
    await pgsql.execute('rollback');
    return new Future.error(err);
  }
  await pgsql.execute('end');
  return new Future.value('OK');
}
```

1. Is the loop of separate inserts right way to insert many rows in Dart postgresql driver?
2. If I use `rate.forEach((row) async {` as above I have wrong execution chain *begin-end-insert-insert* because `.forEach` method calls argument function asynchronously. `rate.forEach(await (row) async {` does the same. Using `await rate.forEach(await (row) async {` gives right chain *begin-insert-insert-end* but inserts are executed asynchronously relative to *begin-end*. Only standard `for(int i=0; i<rate.length; i++) {` loop gives needed result. Is any way to use `.forEach` method in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. it would be much more efficient to insert multiple records in one bigger statement (source https://kaiv.wordpress.com/2007/07/19/faster-insert-for-multiple-rows/)

**Multi-row insert SQL file**

```sql
insert into things (thing) values ('thing nr. 0'),
('thing nr. 1'),
('thing nr. 2'),
('thing nr. 3'),
...
('thing nr. 99999),
('thing nr. 100000);
```

or **Multiple insert statments SQL file**

```sql
begin;
insert into things (thing) values ('thing nr. 0');
insert into things (thing) values ('thing nr. 1');
insert into things (thing) values ('thing nr. 2');
....
insert into things (thing) values ('thing nr. 99999');
insert into things (thing) values ('thing nr. 100000');
commit;
```

2. use

```
await for(row in rate) {
  try {
    await pgsql.execute('insert into t_rate (zone_id,cost) '
      'values (@zone_id,@cost)', row);
  } catch(err) {
    await pgsql.execute('rollback');
    return new Future.error(err);
  }
});
```

instead of

```
rate.forEach((row) async {
```

Comment: Thanks, Günter, I will sum:1) it must use either one specially prepared huge insert or many single inserts - no other special ways, 2) forEach method is not convenient -  use for-loop.

Comment: `await for` usually works better for async/await. There might be a better way with the postgres package but at least don't make a new request for each record. Making the requests too big (hundreds or thousands of records) might slow it down as well especially when run in a big transaction.

Comment: I assume redstone wraps the postgresql driver - but in the postgresql package there is a function called runInTransaction. Works like: conn.runInTransaction(() { conn.execute(...); ... }); This will handle the the transactions and rollbacks for you. Perhaps redstone allows something similar?

Comment: Example here. https://github.com/xxgreg/dart_postgresql/blob/master/test/postgresql_test.dart#L532

Comment: Thanks, Greg, your comment made my code more simple:

    `Future addRPlan(@Decode() List<Rate> rate) {
      return pgsql.innerConn.runInTransaction(() async {
        for (var row in rate) {
          await pgsql.execute('insert into t_rate (zone_id,cost) values (@zone_id,@cost)', row);
        }
      });
    }`